# Unresolved maven android dependency when building in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, viewpagerindicator, android-maven-plugin

I'm using Maven with my Android project, along with the android-maven-plugin. In my project pom.xml file I declare the dependency like so:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.viewpagerindicator</groupId>
  <artifactId>library</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

ViewPagerIndicator has a dependency on Android 4.1.1.4, which is on Maven Central [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.android%7Candroid%7C4.1.1.4%7Cjar).
However, I don't build with Android 4.1.1.4, I build on 4.2.2 r2, which is declared like so:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>android</groupId>
  <artifactId>android</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.2_r2</version>
</dependency>
```

This artifact is NOT on Maven Central, I'm using the [maven-android-sdk-deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) to push Android artifacts into my repo.

If I open up my terminal and build with maven, there's no issue. The issue is when I import my project into IntelliJ and try to build. The module settings (correctly) complain that path to the Android 4.1.1.4 dependency in the ViewPagerIndicator apklib module is broken.

I checked my .m2/repository folder for the Android 4.1.1.4 jar and there's not even a folder for it, which means Maven never downloaded it. I'm guessing it has something to do with the way the maven-android-plugin works when you build with Maven, vs how IntelliJ builds.

I know I can just grab the jar and deploy it myself by hand, but I'm looking for a better solution so new members on my team only need to grab the source code and do nothing else to build the project. I already set up Nexus for the team, so we don't have to keep manually deploying third party jars, and running the sdk deployer on everyone's machine. I'd like to be able to just hand a new dev the source and they can just run with it.

Answer (score 1):

The way it works well for us (in combination with the maven-android-sdk-deployer:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.viewpagerindicator</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>${viewpagerindicator.version}</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

We are also building with IntelliJ. Usually by simply opening the pom.xml file and saying yes to the "Would u like to open this as a project?" prompt.

Comment: If I try to exclude the Android dependencies I can't build, all the classes in ViewPagerIndicator lib that have Android dependencies complain.

Comment: Do you have dependencies on in your pom.xml file on the Android support library? `<dependency>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Yes, but listed like this: `<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
      <version>r13</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: Try using the one I wrote as it's sourcing from the local repo instead of maven central.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the facts: I have the maven project depending on the apklib module buildable by maven itself, but not via intellij. Solution to this situation is following:

1. Import the maven projects into intellij
2. Open apklib module settings and add explicit dependency jars (android, support...) to the module. Do not export this dependency. You can also set the provided scope.

It works for me.